# 15 Pin Joystick (old style PC) to USB solution for OS X

Tags: usb, games

I have a set of old Thrustmaster TCS joysticks.  I'd like to try using them again on my Mac Book Pro to play a flight simulator.  I have seen some DB-15 pin to USB Joystick Adapters, but I have not seen a single one that indicate OS X compatibility.  Has anyone found anything like this that works with OS X?

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is the standard USB joystick interface, those adapters should work with macOS just fine.

You can use programs such as [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html), [Joystick Mapper](http://joystickmapper.com) or [GamePad Companion](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gamepad-companion/id428799479?mt=12) to map the buttons and axes to match your game and joystick.